IIQ 8.4 installation issue
WARN main

springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:559 -
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'versionChecker' defined in class path
resource [configBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to check IdentityIQ
database version: Unable to connect to:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/identityiq?useServerPrepStmts=true&tinyInt1isBit=true&useSSL=false&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC

I tried to set the mysql DB user details on iiq.properties not working.
I tried to update iiq patch 8.4 not working.
Please help to setup the Sailpoint IIQ on my windows 11.

Are you that the MySQL database is listening on an IP port? I believe the default installation uses a socket.
Other things to check:

Check the port (3307 is not the default port, 3306 is default)
Check the credentials used - for testing purposes, you can add the password unencrypted in the iiq.properties. Once it works, make sure to encrypt them using iiq encrypt.
Make sure you are on at least Java 11, or a newer LTS version up to 21 (8.4 is the first version to no longer support Java 8).
Is TLS needed for the connection?
Is the JDBC driver compatible with your database? IdentityIQ comes with with an older JDBC driver that you may want to update to the latest, matching your database.

